# BringToFront and different message pumps

Tags: multithreading, message, bringtofront

I will jump right into the question.
Basically I have set up a program that requires multiple message pumps. However, when a form is in focus and a form that is on a different message pump calls BringToFront, it won't work because it's on a different message pump. Is there any way to fix this?

Damn, I cannot believe I forgot to add that... I am sorry ya'll!
Language: VB.NET
Sample of code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Shared Test As New Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Test.Invoke(Sub() Test.BringToFront())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim T As New Threading.Thread(Sub()

                                          Application.Run(Test)
                                      End Sub)
        T.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I use Invoke() because the form was created on a different thread.

First I press Button2, then I click Form1 again and try to bring Form2 to front using Button1.

Comment: Welcome to SE. You may want to add details to your post (using `Edit`): Which language, sample of code to demonstrate the problem... See [ask] as a guideline.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [AttachThreadInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you're running windows on different threads.